# logstash add_field conversion issue

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash version 5.0.2. Parsing a file which holds a filename as one of the fields which is parsed by logstash grok filter, but for visualization i needed the file number to identify each file. So I added new field through mutate filter add_field checking the filename in [message].

```
  if 'filename_1' in [message] {
       mutate { add_field => { "file_no" => "13" } }
       mutate {convert => [ "file_no", "float" ] }
       }
```

If i check the parsing through stdin/stdout (rubydebug codec) filterit shows the file_no field is converted properly. but if I send the logstash output  to elasticsearch kibana shows conflict in data type of that field. 
there I am able to see file_no.keyword(as string) and file_no(as conflict), with error as:

```
Mapping conflict! A field is defined as several types (string, integer, 
etc) across the indices that match this pattern. You may still be able to use 
these conflict fields in parts of Kibana, but they will be unavailable for 
functions that require Kibana to know their type. Correcting this issue will 
require reindexing your data
```

I have converted the added filed so why is is still being sent to elasticsearch as string not sure. 
any help would be great.

When tried converting the field there is not option of number in Kibana. The source logfile being monitored doesn't have this number to parse it directly as an integer with %{PATTERN_FOR_NUMBER:number_variable:int} otherwise this could have been easier

Comment: Hi, seems like you have older indices referencing that field as something else than float. you should check the mappings of all the indices matching your Kibana index pattern. assuming for example the indices have names like v_sukt-2017.03.06, and your pattern is v_sukt-*, then you can retrieve all the mappings with the command GET v_sukt-*/_mappings Then you just check for the file_no field and see how it is mapped in each indice

Comment: hi @Olivier, I don't have any backup of old indices, If I delete it. is there any way to get the old data. OR to re-index the old indices

Comment: Without backup (called snapshots), deleting an index is losing the data. Creating snapshots is quite easy, you should look into that (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/modules-snapshots.html assuming the whole stack is the version you referenced: 5.0.x). Considering the field is new, I'd expect the number of events - and indices - with the "wrong" mapping to be quite limited, could you check how many are impacted?